# Python Pandas writing to excel without bolding and boarders

Tags: python, pandas, output

I am using pandas to load and write an excel file

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

os.getcwd()
os.chdir("C:/Users/0/Desktop/python")

data=pd.read_excel('excelsample.xlsx', 0, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
data2=pd.read_excel('excelsample.xlsx', 1, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

data.a +=2


with ExcelWriter('aa.xlsx') as writer:
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    data2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

The data comes out like this on console

```
>>> data
   a  b  c  d  Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5
0  3  2  3  4         NaN      total
1  5  4  4  6         NaN          5
2  7  5  3  3         NaN        NaN

[3 rows x 6 columns]

>>> data2
  hello pandas
0     a      s
1     d      g

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

When I save it, it automatically does the following:

- adds 'Unnamed: 4' and 'Unnamed: 5'
- bolds and puts boarders around my indexes
- saves the default index

how do I save it so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

As excel can read in CSV files, you could just export to CSV.

Comment: By doing that you would get rid of one sheet or have 2 files.